GA4 analytics data api gives html report instead of json
i am trying to fetch data from analytics data api, but my web page keep showing Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON, i tried to test the type of file got from api, it is always html, and i tried many ways to convert this html into json, but it always fail, so I wonder what should I do to fix it. Thannk you so much for the help.
my server code:
part1
part2
my client code:
part1
thank you, i used postman to test it, it has a response, but just in html form.
i tried to convert it into json in server side, but it didn't work, and I tested it on web using inspect as well, still html.
so now I think the main problem is that the html response got from api won;t convert into json.

DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? Please [edit] your question to include the text.
